# color swatches won't swap images on custom theme magento 1.9.1

Tags: rwd, ce-1.9.1.0, color-swatches, swatches

After following the tutorial from "format" to apply the color swatches on an custom theme in magento.

Everything shows nice and neat, even the zoom works.

However I can't get the product image to swap when a customer would click the color swatch...

Does someone have a tip or idea where to find the error?

I've setup a test site where I'm making the changes:
www.fietsenwinkelonline.be

Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

the javascript and functionality of the 1.9.1 color swatch features is built into the rwd/default package/theme, and not any other package/theme. Most templates are built on default/default or base/default which do not include that functionality.

More Detailed 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches

Comment: Thanks for your post!!!
Is it possible to implement those features? This is my first crack at something like this and so far i've got it running that the swatches are available in the layerd navigation and on the product page.
So the only thing would be the automatic switch for product image when i click the swatch...
Any pointers maybe?

EDIT: Maybe this helps, i've followed this tutorial:
http://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have either:

1. an image added to each associated simple product (and set as Base)
2. an image on the configurable with a label with just the color attribute label name?

You may also need to look at the section on localization:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches#swap